# Unable to authenticate in accessing Dynamic CRM Online Web Service

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I need to utilize Dynamic CRM Data Service Endpoint exposed to get data from one of the methods.
Service(microsoft) account has access to this service.
 I've tried authenticating to Discovery Service and Organization Service using sample code provided here [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675404.aspx] and succeed. However am not able to use same authentication to access data Service as I could find anyway  to relate Data Service with the other two. Doing basic authentication using Network Credentials does not work.

I have downloaded the CSDL exposed and added that as service reference to my project, which created an class of web service which extends from DataServiceContext. Am trying to retrieve data of one of the methods using LinQ queries. It returs following error:

"The response payload is a not a valid response payload. Please make sure that the top level element is a valid Atom or JSON element or belongs to 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' namespace." On capturing using fiddle I realized that on hitting data service URL it is redirected to sign in  page 'login.microsoftonline.com/'

Can anybody suggest a way to authenticate the user to access Data Serivce?

Adding code:

```
//<snippetAuthenticateWithNoHelp1>
            IServiceManagement<IDiscoveryService> serviceManagement =
                        ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<IDiscoveryService>(
                        new Uri(_discoveryServiceAddress));
            AuthenticationProviderType endpointType = serviceManagement.AuthenticationType;

            // Set the credentials.
            AuthenticationCredentials authCredentials = GetCredentials(serviceManagement, endpointType);


            String organizationUri = String.Empty;
            // Get the discovery service proxy.
            using (DiscoveryServiceProxy discoveryProxy =
                GetProxy<IDiscoveryService, DiscoveryServiceProxy>(serviceManagement, authCredentials))
            {
                // Obtain organization information from the Discovery service. 
                if (discoveryProxy != null)
                {
                    // Obtain information about the organizations that the system user belongs to.
                    OrganizationDetailCollection orgs = DiscoverOrganizations(discoveryProxy);
                    // Obtains the Web address (Uri) of the target organization.
                    organizationUri = FindOrganization(_organizationUniqueName,
                        orgs.ToArray()).Endpoints[EndpointType.OrganizationService];

                }
            }
            //</snippetAuthenticateWithNoHelp1>


            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(organizationUri))
            {
                //<snippetAuthenticateWithNoHelp3>
                IServiceManagement<IOrganizationService> orgServiceManagement =
                    ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<IOrganizationService>(
                    new Uri(organizationUri));

                // Set the credentials.
                AuthenticationCredentials credentials = GetCredentials(orgServiceManagement, endpointType);

                // Get the organization service proxy.
                using (OrganizationServiceProxy organizationProxy =
                    GetProxy<IOrganizationService, OrganizationServiceProxy>(orgServiceManagement, credentials))
                {
                    // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
                    organizationProxy.EnableProxyTypes();

                    // Now make an SDK call with the organization service proxy.
                    // Display information about the logged on user.
                    Guid userid = ((WhoAmIResponse)organizationProxy.Execute(
                        new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;
                    SystemUser systemUser = organizationProxy.Retrieve("systemuser", userid,
                        new ColumnSet(new string[] { "firstname", "lastname" })).ToEntity<SystemUser>();
                    Console.WriteLine("Logged on user is {0} {1}.",
                        systemUser.FirstName, systemUser.LastName);
                    Uri x = new Uri("https://<MyOrgainzationName>.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/");
                    MyOrgainzationContext saContext = new MyOrgainzationContext(x);
                    NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential();
                    nc.UserName = "*****@microsoft.com";
                    nc.Password = "********";
                    saContext.Credentials = nc;
                    var query_where3 = from c in saContext.new_productSet
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           ProductStatus = c.new_ProductStatus,
                                           LineofBusiness = c.new_LineofBusiness
                                       };
                    var temp = saContext.Entities;
                    foreach (var c in query_where3)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("ProductStatus: " +
                         c.ProductStatus +
                         "\t\t\t" +
                         "LineofBusiness: " +
                         c.LineofBusiness);

                    }
                }
                //</snippetAuthenticateWithNoHelp3>

            }
```

MyOrganizationContext is the context class created on adding CSDL file exposed at service endpoints

Comment: google "dynamics crm simplified connection"

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to access the OData endpoint from outside of xRM? Would help if you posted your code.

Comment: Yes James through console application. Is it possible at all ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the CRM Web Api Preview: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm/webapipreview.aspx. You can call this endpoint from outside xRM and you can authenticate with OAuth 2.0.